# How to fix button position at the time of scrolling window

Tags: jquery, css

I wants to fix prevbutton and nextbutton position.
   How do I use the jquery scroll event for that?

```
 <div class="content">
    <div class="items">
        dfjdslkfjdls;ajfdls;jkfa;fd;lsjfl;dsasjfl;akjf
    <div class="prev button">prev</div>
    <div class="next button">next</div>
 </div>
```

//jquery

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.button').addClass('fixed'); // within contnet
    }
    else {
        $('.button').removeClass('fixed'); // within content
    }
});
```

see jfiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/deN3g/2/

Comment: Have you got any error or what you want? Given example does not working for you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deN3g/4/ is this what you want?

Comment: i wanted top 50% middle

Comment: yes answer is very good.. that right.. but i wanted button is middle

Comment: i wanted you answer vote up and i like this...

Comment: @NyaungBinHla looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/deN3g/7/

Comment: but i wanted within contentClass fixed buttonprev and next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test my code

```
 function loadswitharrow(){

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 0) {
            $('.button').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
            $('.button').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    }); 
}
```

css

```
  .fixed{position:fixed;}
  .prevbutton{left:-3%;}
  .nextbutton{right:-3%;}
  .fixed.nextbutton{right:17%;}
  .fixed.prevbutton{left:17%;}
```